# Validate a OTA.zip

Tags: stock-android, ota-update, device-firmware, manufacturers

Can i validate a ota.zip for my phone? 
I want to check, if a downloaded OTA from somewhere origins to the manufacurer.
I thought about signatures.

Comment: Signatures will be checked in the recovery, stock recovery will not install anything not signed by the OEM. What about the MD5 of the file with the manufacturer?

Comment: Ok i found that inside of OTA is file updater-script which checks the apk´s. But for me i want to check the whole .zip file. I found PEM certificate inside the OTA named otacert. My Android has the same stored in /security/etc/otacerts.zip
But i dont no how i could manually validate the ota.zip with a checksum and or the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. It is all explained on http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2013/04/android-code-signing.html
I compared the PEM certificate within the ota.zip (META-INF/com/android/otacert) with the one stored on my phone in /security/etc/otacerts.zip.

To verify the whole ota.zip wit openssl:

```
openssl smime -verify -in /META-INF/CERT.RSA -inform DER -content ota_seperated.zip otacert.pem
```

Comment: Since the OTA is signed with `jarsigner` (or at least it's in the same format), you can also just do `jarsigner -verify update.zip -certs -verbose`, where `update.zip` is the OTA update.